# C# POST request works on POSTMAN but not on C# HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, http, post, httpwebrequest

I'm getting code 400 only in C# and when I use post man I get 200!
It has the same properties.

I initally created the classes as JSONProperty attributes and still after decentralize I get code 400.

Found on fiddler innder exception -
message=parameters : The property 'Changedby' does not exist on type 'XXXXX.AzureAd.XXX.Types.NewDescriptionEntry'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.

[image]
The JSON in the debugging mode in C# after creating the classes - JSON mode.

[image]

```
 // Serialize our concrete class into a JSON String
                var stringPayload = await Task.Run(() => 

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload_transferIncident));

            // build the URL we'll hit
            var url = string.Format("https://XXXXXX", "YYYYY", id, "XXXX");

            //create the request
           var req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);

            //add in the cert we'll authenticate with
             req.ClientCertificates.Add(IcmIncidentOperation.GetCert("XXXXXX"));

            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            req.Method = "POST";
            if (req == null)
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Could not create the httprequest from the url:{0}", url));
            try
            {
                using (var streamWriter =   new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(stringPayload);
                }
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            }
```

Comment: I encourage you to debug this code, you will see immediately that you are writing nothing to the request stream. What you intend to do is write the result of the serialization of `payload_transferIncident` to it but your code does not assign that to any variable, it just discards it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way using **HttpRequest** POST METHOD

```
try
        {
            var baseAddress = new Uri("Your base url");

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = baseAddress
            })
            {
                var json =Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject( payload);

                using (var content = new StringContent( json, System.Text.Encoding.Default, "application/json"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("end-point url method", content))
                        {

                            result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        return ex.Message;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.Message;
        }
```